# I get a blank screen rather than a Screen Saver

Tags: 11.04, compiz, screensaver, acer

When my Screen saver is due to start I just get a blank screen. I have recently installed Compiz, before the screen saver worked as normal.
I don't get locked out or any major problem but I just see a blank screen rather than one of the pre-installed screen-savers.

Comment: Two quick (maybe obvious) things to check. Be sure to check power management settings to see if your screen is set to turn off after some time. Also, I think the default Ubuntu screensaver is just a blank screen, so make sure your screensaver is set to something else.

Comment: Screen saver set to FuzzyFlakes and power management set to never. Still get a fading blank screen instead.

Comment: Problem seems to have gone away. Screensavers now start with the settings to 5mins (not less). I still get a blank screen if I set settings to 1 or 2 mins.

Answer (score 1):

*(OP states issue resolved)*

Problem seems to have gone away. Screensavers now start with the settings to 5mins (not less). I still get a blank screen if I set settings to 1 or 2 mins. – motoringeek Aug 23 '11 at 22:15